# Callback when cache expires in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know a tutorial or an example on how can i run a function in asp.net, when a cache expires? I have read about a callback which is made when a cache expires, but i didn't find any examples. I need this for a website. It needs to execute a function on an exact hour every day.

Comment: Do you have access to the hosting, I mean can you run commands and configure a service, I found that the save way of doing this is making a console application and use the task manager to schedule it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hhh3112,

You can use a callback when the cache expires.  can you explain a little more. I am not sure what you mean by the process has to execute on an exact hour of everyday.

```
string test = "test1";
Cache.Insert("Key", test, dependancy, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheRemovedCallback));

public string CacheRemovedCallback(String key, object value, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason removedReason)
{
    //Do something here
    return  = "Cache Expired for : " + key;
}
```

Comment: Using Cache.Insert, can i set the respective cache to expire at an exact date, and when it does expire to execute the CacheRemovedCallback?

Answer (score 1):

See [**CacheItemRemovedCallback**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx) in the following [**ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx).