# Is there a way to run custom code on Azure Cache expiration? (where last cached value is accessible)

Tags: azure, azure-caching

What I mean is a kind of event or callback which is called when some cached value is expiring. Supposedly this callback should be given the currenlty cached value, for example, to store it somewhere else apart from caching.

To find such a way, I have reviewed [Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914156.aspx) option, but they look like they are applicable for explicit actions with cache like adding or removing, whereas expiration is a kind of thing that occurs implicitly. I found out that none of these callbacks is not called many minutes after cache value has expired and has become `null`, while it is called normally within polling interval if I call `DataCache.Remove` explicitly (wrong, see update below).

I find this behavior strange as ASP.Net has such callback. You can even find an explanation how to utilize it [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116223/callback-when-cache-expires-in-asp-net).

Also, I tried [DataCache Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh147550.aspx). It is writtent in MSDN that literally

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Nevertheless I created a handler for these event to see if I can test its args like `CacheOperationStartedEventArgs.OperationType == CacheOperationType.ClearCache` but it seemed to be in vain.

At the moment, I started to think about workarounds of this issue of the lack of required callback. So suggestions how to implement them are welcome too.

UPDATE. After more attentive and patient testing I found out that notification with `DataCacheOperations.ReplaceItem` is sent after expiration. Regrettably, I did not find the way to get the value that was cached before the expiration had occurred.

Comment: It would certainly be great to be able to capture the before/after cached value on ReplaceItem. I recommend adding this suggestion to Microsoft's ASP.NET User Voice site: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net