# Refresh cache every few minutes in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a asp.net web application. I add some data, which is read from database, to HttpContext.Cache but I want the data to be reread from database every 15 minutes and set it in the cache. How do I do this? I am adding the entry in the cache to expire after 15 minutes. I looked into 'CacheItemRemovedCallback' when adding data to cache object but in this callback HttpContext is not initialized, it is returing null, so, I can't add the data to the cache back. Is there a mechanism that can acheive this?

Comment: Can you just check to see if the cache key is null or empty when you load the page. Then, if empty, repopulate? That would also prevent issues if an application pool restarts.

Comment: I am doing that already but the data that is needed to be set is little bit on the larger side and takes couple of seconds and I am trying to avoid the delay on page load for the users.

Comment: You just need `System.Web.Caching.Cache` to create a cache when `CacheItemRemovedCallback` is called. Do you need to retrieve something from `HttpContext` before creating a cache?

Comment: I don't know much about Cache but I am using cache from HttpContext to store the data. If I use Cache class directly instead of using cache from HttpContext, does it create seperate instance of cache? I have other data I cache too, I want to use only one Cache instance. Also, what is the difference between HttpConext.Cache and plain Cache?

Comment: Ok, I read some about Cache and I was using HttpContext.Current to get Cache which is null on the CacheItemRemovedCallback. Instead I used HttpRuntime.Cache, as HttpContext.Current.Cache also returns the same, and it is working fine. Thanks for helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a time event to repopulate the cache at the required intervals like so from the application start event in your global.asax.  This won't delay the UI for any users.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Timer customTimer = new Timer();
    customTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(YourHandler.YourRepopulationEvent);
    customTimer.Interval = YourInterval;
    customTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I never used Application_Start event, because of your post I looked it up and learned something new. For my above scenerio, I will go with using callback with HttpRuntime.Cache instead of HttpContext.Current.Cache. I understand that the cache will not be ready untill the first request to the page. I think I will live with it.

Answer (score 1):

probably you can use callback with caching. please refer below link
[Callback when cache expires in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116223/callback-when-cache-expires-in-asp-net)